# An initWithCoder method does not return a value

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to resolve an application crash on startup. I made some mods to my app and now it crashes with the following message:
This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder
I made very small changes and I haven't done anything outside of the norm other than introduce a few IBOutlets in two view controllers. They both need to share an NSMutableDictionary for configuration purposes. I can't figure this out as everything was working fine before. :( I'm not calling initWithCoder directly anywhere and there's nothing in the stack that indicates anything I've done wrong. It's hinting towards the nib changes I made which don't make any sense! Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seconds after posting I removed the NSMutableDictionary custom object from my nib and the crash goes away. I guess I cannot load/instantiate dictionary objects from a nib? This is odd and frustrating. I'm trying to forego the need for a dependency injection framework (objection) which is why I'm trying to use the nib file to load and wire everything together.